# How to set a variable in my assignment rule

Tags: customsetting, assignment-rules

What I am trying to achieve is create a universal variable in salesforce which I can access in my assignment rule.

I will set that variable to some value through UI. Assignment rule will check if that variable is = xyz then assign to queue1 if that variable is = abc then assign to queue2 ... and so on.

So which functionality in salesforce should I use to create a variable and access it in assignment rules? Will custom setting do? I am not sure about this because can't access list custom settings in assignment rule criteria formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `Hierarchy Custom Settings` from an `Assignment Rule`. Then when you want to reference them, use a formula for your criteria and reference them through the `$Setup` global variable:

```
CASE($Setup.MyHierarchySetting.SomeField__c,
    "ABC", "Value 1",
    "XYZ", "Value 2",
    "Fallback"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Custom Label` and assign a value from UI.

Create the assignment rule based on formula entry and access this variable.

`$Label.My_Label = Somevalue`

Note that, value will be assigned from UI and it is not dynamically get changed by any coding.